# Ascribing multiple OCaml Signatures to a Module

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

Ocaml combining signatures

Suppose I have two signatures, Ordered, and Field

```
module type ORDERED = sig 
    type t
    type comparison = LT | EQ | GT
    val cmp : t -> t -> comparison
end

module type FIELD = sig
    type t
    val (+) : t -> t -> t
    val ( * ) : t -> t -> t
    val inv : t -> t
    val neg : t -> t
    val zero : t
    val one : t
end
```

And I want to make a functor that takes two `Ordered Fields` and produces another `Ordered Field` (say operations are applied component-wise and we use dictionary order for comparison). How would I specify that the "input modules" satisfy two signatures simultaneously?

Here is some strawman syntax for what I want to do:

```
module NaivePair = functor (Left : ORDERED & FIELD) (Right : ORDERED & FIELD) ->
    struct
        type t = Left.t * Right.t
        (* definitions *)
    end
```

It might be the case that there's an elegant way to take a "union" of signatures (but not an anonymous union), or create a wrapper module around concrete `ORDERED` and `FIELD` implementations that just happen to share a type t. I am curious what the idiomatic OCaml way to do what I am trying to achieve is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a new module type using `include` and `with type t := t`:

```
module type ORDERED_FIELD = sig
  include ORDERED
  include FIELD with type t := t
end
```

Without `with type t := t`, the definition is rejected since both `ORDERED` and `FIELD` declares the type of the same name. `include FIELD with type t := t` is to "substitute" `t` of `FIELD` by `ORDERED.t`.

`ocamlc -i -c x.ml` to see what `ORDERED_FIELD` is exactly what you want:

```
$ ocamlc -i -c x.ml
...
...
module type ORDERED_FILED =
  sig
    type t
    type comparison = LT | EQ | GT
    val cmp : t -> t -> comparison
    val ( + ) : t -> t -> t
    val ( * ) : t -> t -> t
    val inv : t -> t
    val neg : t -> t
    val zero : t
    val one : t
  end
```

Comment: Can a module type be first-class?

Comment: How would you use this functor? Can you provide an example, @erwaman? Thanks for sharing.